# ssh into ubuntu clean install, ssh by wifi is ok but by cable host unreachable

Tags: networking, ubuntu, ssh, raspberry-pi, home-networking

I have problems using putty on a rpi3 headless. This is not the first time using it but i want to start a home security project and start testing things. I'm sure is not a Rpi or pc problem nor ubuntu or windows, it has to be something on my network. Question was asked on askubuntu but since they said it was nothing to do with them i'm posting it here.

Started installing raspios buster, can't ssh.
Then installed raspios bullseye, same.
Then used ubuntu 22.04 live server, same.
Finally ubuntu 22.04 preinstalled server (this time with my touchscreen + BT peripherals)

Since then, used the screen to see what's happening and saw everything is ok but can't ssh into it. Tried my wife's pc with the same result, then remembered my laptop aaaaaaand lucky! using wifi from the laptop i can reach the rpi and ssh into it BUT then connected the laptop to the modem using cable and surprise, surprise, it have the same problem my computer have. Laptop is using 2.4Ghz wifi. Only using one router and it's in the same network (ip range and subnet matches).

More proofs that the rpi and the pc are on the same network:
"arp -a" before pinging the pc from the rpi
then pinging the pc from the rpi
"arp -a" after the pinging showing the rpi IP on the list.

```
Interfaz: 192.168.1.134 --- 0x8
  Dirección de Internet          Dirección física      Tipo
  192.168.1.1           44-ad-b1-c9-c9-71     dinámico
  192.168.1.130         d4-9d-c0-c5-a2-04     dinámico
  192.168.1.131         94-e9-79-17-4c-af     dinámico
  192.168.1.133         e6-08-8e-4b-5a-63     dinámico
  192.168.1.255         ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     estático
  224.0.0.22            01-00-5e-00-00-16     estático
  224.0.0.251           01-00-5e-00-00-fb     estático
  224.0.0.252           01-00-5e-00-00-fc     estático
  239.255.255.250       01-00-5e-7f-ff-fa     estático
  255.255.255.255       ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     estático

C:\Users\Zaragan>ipconfig

Configuración IP de Windows

Adaptador de Ethernet Ethernet:

   Sufijo DNS específico para la conexión. . : home
   Vínculo: dirección IPv6 local. . . : fe80::cd5b:2008:8339:5a8f%8
   Dirección IPv4. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.134
   Máscara de subred . . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Puerta de enlace predeterminada . . . . . : 192.168.1.1

C:\Users\Zaragan>arp -a

Interfaz: 192.168.1.134 --- 0x8
  Dirección de Internet          Dirección física      Tipo
  192.168.1.1           44-ad-b1-c9-c9-71     dinámico
  192.168.1.130         d4-9d-c0-c5-a2-04     dinámico
  192.168.1.131         94-e9-79-17-4c-af     dinámico
  192.168.1.133         e6-08-8e-4b-5a-63     dinámico
  192.168.1.148         b8-27-eb-a1-e9-9d     dinámico
  192.168.1.255         ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     estático
  224.0.0.22            01-00-5e-00-00-16     estático
  224.0.0.251           01-00-5e-00-00-fb     estático
  224.0.0.252           01-00-5e-00-00-fc     estático
  239.255.255.250       01-00-5e-7f-ff-fa     estático
  255.255.255.255       ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     estático

C:\Users\Zaragan>
```

Any clues? Why using the wifi i can ssh into it and using cable i can't?

---

Things i tried:

1. Change ssh port
2. Configure ufw (add rule, remove rule, enable and disable ufw)
3. Check netplan, change ip's, dns
4. Check/change home group
5. Check gateways
6. Reinstall windows
7. Update windows to win11
8. Fresh win10 install
9. Rpi is in DMZ
10. Update the router firmware (Sagecom F@st 5657)

---

- [laptop details info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QanS7.jpg)
- [laptop network cmd info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BS5UG.jpg)
- [computer network info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uWfh.png)
- [sshd config (changed port, rest is default)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UU1Pj.jpg)
- [netplan config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XR1A.jpg)
- [resolv config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZMNT.jpg)
- [ssh status (it shows the connection from the laptop on wifi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgsDT.jpg)
- [ip addr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Owgug.jpg)
- ifconfig (i.stack.imgur.com/G5mct.jpg) only 8 links allowed

Comment: You don’t indicate the IP address of your Raspberry. Then, it is impossible to analyse your screen copy. We may suppose it is 192.168.1.148. The error of putty should be indicated too. It may be Network error: Connection timed out. or something else.

Comment: From a shell on the Raspberry, type `netstat -a`. This should indicates the ports `ssh` is listening.